# Access Denied while installing SQL server 2016

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

I am getting the below error while installing SQL Server, when I've selected the domain account for SQL server engine startup account and press next.

```
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp: Sco: Attempting to check if container 'WinNT://DOMAIN' of user account exists
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp: Prompting user if they want to retry this action due to the following failure:
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp: ----------------------------------------
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp: The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp: Inner exceptions are being indented
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp: 
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp: Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.ScoException
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:     Message: 
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:         Access is denied.
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:         
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:     HResult : 0x84bb0001
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:         FacilityCode : 1211 (4bb)
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:         ErrorCode : 1 (0001)
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:     Data: 
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:       WatsonData = Domain
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:       DisableRetry = true
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:     Inner exception type: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:         Message: 
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:                 Access is denied.
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:                 
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:         HResult : 0x80070005
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:         Stack: 
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:                 at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAdsContainer.GetObject(String className, String relativeName)
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:                 at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.Find(String name, String schemaClassName)
(11) 2020-02-16 14:58:48 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.User.LookupADEntry()
```

I am installing SQL server 2016 STD version on Windows Server 2016 OS which is joined to a Domain controller.

Note:  I can install by selecting Local System as the startup account. later I can change through the configuration manager.  I can't do this workaround for Cluster installation.

Anybody faced this issue?

Comment: Please check this answer- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55940/136766